# VSTO ListObject rename event

Tags: excel, vsto

Is there an event that can be used to handle renaming of an Excel table (ListObject)? The `SheetChange` event does not seem to fire for name changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: It doesn't look like there's an event for this.

I subscribed to all workbook events with the below code and none of them fire when a Range or a ListObject are renamed.

Caveat: for some reason, I could not get a list of events for the active sheet object, probably a COM interop thing (GetEvents() returns an empty array) and I did not have time to investigate. It's possible that there's an event on the sheet object for this, although I suspect it's unlikely.

```cs
foreach (var eventInfo in workbook.GetType().GetEvents())
{
    string name = eventInfo.Name;

    var parameters = eventInfo.EventHandlerType
        .GetMethod("Invoke")
        .GetParameters()
        .Select(parameter => Expression.Parameter(parameter.ParameterType))
        .ToArray();

    var handler = Expression.Lambda(
            eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
            Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(new System.Action(() => Trace.WriteLine($"Event: {name}"))), "Invoke", Type.EmptyTypes),
            parameters)
        .Compile();

    eventInfo.AddEventHandler(workbook, handler);
}
```